# LibreDraw runs very slowly in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, intel-graphics, performance

After upgrading to Lubuntu 22.04, LibreDraw is running very slowly to the extent that it's unusable, from being completely fine on release 18. I'm running it on a laptop with a Pentium P6100 / 8G dram / Intel HD graphics. I've completely reinstalled Lubuntu and LibreOffice, but it's still running like a dog. Any ideas?

Comment: which version of LO are you using? the deb version, Snap or Flatpak?

Comment: It's the standard version which comes with the Lubuntu distro, so I imagine the deb version. I did try the latest snap release but that was even slower and took ages to open. Version: 7.3.7.2 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 30(Build:2)
CPU threads: 2; OS: Linux 6.5; UI render: default; VCL: qt5 (cairo+xcb)
Locale: en-GB (en_GB.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Ubuntu package version: 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4
Calc: threaded